# BASH - add prefix (file path) to each line in text file using awk

Tags: bash, awk, filepath

I am trying to get the full path of a files within a directory. So far this is what I have in bash.

```
prefix="s3://${s3_bucket}/${s3_folder}/$(date --date="$i days ago" +"%Y/%m/%d")/"
#echo $prefix
aws s3 ls s3://${s3_bucket}/${s3_folder}/$(date --date="$i days ago" +"%Y/%m/%d")/ | sed -n 's/.*\([0-9][0-9]-h.*gz\)/\1/p' | awk '$0="${prefix}"$0' >> ${s3_files_1}
```

In my output, I am getting the following:

```
${prefix}file1.gz  
${prefix}file2.gz
```

The output I am looking for is something like below.

```
s3://my_bucket/my_folder/file1.gz
s3://my_bucket/my_folder/file2.gz
```

My issue is with the way the awk command is interpreting the variable ${prefix}. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Awk is not shell, it is a completely different tool/language that you can CALL from shell. You cannot access the value of shell variables directly in an awk program any more than you could in a C program. See @thatotherguy's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `-v` to pass shell variable contents to awk:

```
prefix="s3://my_bucket/my_folder/"
echo "file1.gz" | awk -v myprefix="${prefix//\\/\\\\}" '{ print myprefix $0 }'
```

Sadly, `awk -v` is not data safe. This example uses parameter expansion to escape backslashes to avoid them being mangled.